# EPPlus in .NETCore produces different results for exact same code

Tags: .net-core, epplus

I have code that I copied and pasted directly between a console app built in .NETFramework 4.7.1 and .NETCore 2.2 and I get completely different results when executing.  At first I was using Intersect but when I started getting different results.  Here's the code:

```
var data = ReadDataFromSpreadSheet();

using (var source = new SqlConnection("myconnection"))
{
    source.Open();
    var queryData = source.Query<Model>(SelectSQL).ToList();
    var results = new List<string>();
    foreach (var accountId in data)
    {
        var a = queryData.SingleOrDefault(x =>
            x.AccountNumber == accountId);
        if (a != null)
            results.Add(accountId);
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WTF!");
        }
    }
    var intersect = data.Intersect(queryData.Select(x => x.AccountNumber)).ToList();
    results = results.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Results = " + results.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Instersect = " + results.Count);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The results in .NETFramework are about 1750 rows that are in the spreadsheet data NOT in the Model data.  The .NETCore version is about 730 rows.  Notice that the loop OR the Intersect give the same values so I guess the problem is in the Equals method?

Comment: So can you reproduce it using hard-coded data without the database access? That would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Maybe it's related to [.NET Core having a different `String.GetHashCode` implementation](https://andrewlock.net/why-is-string-gethashcode-different-each-time-i-run-my-program-in-net-core/)?

Comment: I will work on replicating with hard coded data.  If it is due to a different `GetHashCode` implementation that seems it would be really bad.

Answer (score 2):

UGH!  @JonSkeet and @joesewel thank you for responding.  Turns out the .net core version of Epplus changed the worksheet index from 1 to 0 that's why a complete 100% copy of the code didn't work the same between .NETCore and Framework.  <>

Comment: Turns out you can change to make behave the same. From [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/): _Breaking change in .NET Core: The Worksheets collection will be zero based as default.
This can be altered by setting the ExcelPackage.Compatibility.IsWorksheets1Based to true.
.NET Core will have this property set to false, and .Net 3.5 and .Net 4 version will have this property set to true for backward compatibility reasons.
This property can also be set via the appsettings.json file in .Net Core or the app.config file._